# Get data from another class

Tags: java, class

I'm building an application and i am trying to find a way to get data from one class to another class.

in my main class called **Driver**, i have a function which throws two dices and then i get a sum of them. This function is created in a class called **Dices**.
I have a new class called **Players**, where i need to get the data from the dice throw from my main class.

The code is the following

```
public class Player {
public String spillernavn;
public int pos;



public String SpillerNavn() {
        return spillernavn;
    }
public int move(int steps){
  move=??;
  pos=steps+pos;
    return ??;
}
public int SpillerPos() {
        return pos;
    }
}
```

The Methode `public int move(int steps){}` is where i need to use the data from the dice throw and then make the addition with the pos, which stands for position.

The main function is the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Intializing dices
        Dice die1 = new Dice();
        Dice die2 = new Dice();

        //Summ of dice
        int sum = die1.throwDice() + die2.throwDice();
```

Comment: Shouldn't the Drive class hold Player and Dice variables and do the actual dice throwing? It doesn't look like your main method should be doing this.

Comment: Your right. But how can i do this. Im trying to figured out, but no luck.

Comment: We'll never know what you're doing wrong if you don't show us your attempt. Please show us your Driver class or class attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File name: `Dice.java`

```
import java.util.Random; 



public class Dice {

    private Random random;

    public Dice() {

        random = new Random();
    }  

    public int throwDice() {

        int num = 0;

        while(num == 0)  // Dice doesn't have a zero, so keep looping unless dice has a zero.
            num = random.nextInt(7);  // returns a random number between 0 - 6

        return num;
    }
}
```

File name: `Players.java`

```
public class Players {

    private int sum;


    public Players(int sum) {

        this.sum = sum;  // You got the data from `Driver class` here.
        // You got the sum of two dice. Now do whatever you want to.
    }
}  

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Dice dye1 = new Dice();
        Dice dye2 = new Dice(); 
        int sum = dye1.throwDice() + dye2.throwDice();
        Players player = new Player(sum);  // Passing the data to Class Players
    }    
}
```

To send data, you need to pass the argument in the `()`

Comment: Sorry my bad. But when i println i get "Players@7852e922"

Comment: You need to create a method in `class Player` which returns the sum. And print that value.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```
public class Player {
public String spillernavn;
public int pos;



public String SpillerNavn() {
    return spillernavn;
}

public int move(int steps, int move){
    move=move;
    pos=steps+pos;
    return ??;
}

public int SpillerPos() {
    return pos;
}
}
```

Then in main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Intializing dices
    Dice die1 = new Dice();
    Dice die2 = new Dice();

    //Summ of dice
    int sum = die1.throwDice() + die2.throwDice();  

    player.move(steps, move);
```

For future reference. You should probably create an instance of your dice in your player class. It's simple passing data between classes. Getters and setters.